Android Wear app to set watch reminders for kids via parental controls
How hard would it be to set an app to remind kids in school or adults to drink water to stay hydrated?
This would be perfect via an Android watch app, perhaps even with a parental control to set the alarms on the watch by uploading voice or text or video messages to be played on the Android watch while it vibrates at future times, perhaps also setting time intervals via the app.
Wouldn't that be nice?
Thanks.

Doesn't the clock have an alarm function?
